# how to printf a int struct member

Tags: c, struct, printf, member

My program asks client to input name and each time the int num increases by 1. My problem is when i printf the info the int num shows thousands! I think it shows the address.

```
typedef struct myphonebook {
    int num;
    char name[31];
    char address[101];
    char cellphone[11];
    char email[21];
} Myphonebooktype;

Myphonebooktype *pb = NULL;

for(i = addcounter, cc = addcounter + 1; i < 21; i++, cc++) {

    pb = (Myphonebooktype*)realloc(pb,cc*sizeof(Myphonebooktype));

    pb[0].num = 1;

    printf("Add a contact\n");

    printf("Contact no. %d\nEnter name);
    gets(pb[i].name);
    pb[i].num++;            
}
```

this is my print function

```
printf("Contact no %d\nName:%s", pb[i].num, pb[i].name);
```

I initialize the pb[0].num the first one only to one, and auto add using pb[i].num++, and then print, but when i print it shows me not 1 or 2 but 7thousand something plus.

Comment: Where do you initialise `pb[i].num`?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the string token in the format string. Try this:

```
printf("Contact no %d\nName: %s", pb[i].num, pb[i].name);
```

Also, as @Oli Charlesworth commented, you don't initilaise all of the `pb[].num` variables, only the first one. So replace this

```
pb[0].num = 1;
```

With this

```
pb[i].num = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the other issues away and focus on your main one..

There's no "*string*" output in your code, "**%d**" means "**output an integer"** but I don't see any "**%s**" which means "**output a string**"

This is correct

```
printf("Contact no %d\nName: %s", pb[i].num, pb[i].name);
```

Even if fixed, I don't think anything's going to work: you're not initializing `pb[i].num`